# defined var is null when use abstract method

Tags: java, android, class, methods, abstract

I have `class A` with an`abstract method`, and `class B` which extends `class A`.

`abstract method` is called when creating new class object.

In `class B` I have defined a global variable, but when I try to use this variable it appears to be null. In theory this `var` is defined and initialized.

My code:

```
public abstract class A{

public abstract void someMethod();

public A(){
    someMethod();  
}

}


public class B extends class A{
 Rectangle[] mPathDots=new Rectangle[30]; //initialized array with 30  nulled items

 @Override
 someMethod(){
   int x = mPathDots.length; //error! mPathDots is null, but in theory lenght must be 30 !?
 }
}
```

creating:

```
B b = new B();
```

why is `mPathDots` null?
I tried to create a `class B` object without the `abstract method` and it works without any problem, but with `abstract method` this `var` is nulled.

Comment: A is created before B.   and don't do this!

Comment: i need to do this, because i need much more classes extended from A

Comment: @user2052497 what these users mean is that you should not put an abstract method in your abstract class constructor.

Comment: so you need to call super and pass the instance of your array

Comment: @user2052497 You need to find a different solution then. For example, you could just move the code from `someMethod()` to the constructor for `B`.

Comment: public B (Rectangle[] mPathDots) { super (mPathDots)}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason you get a `NullPointerException` is because `new B()` first calls the constructor for `A` **then** calls the constructor for `B`. The fields in `B` are not initialized until at the very beginning of the second constructor call.

**Suggestion:**

One possible solution is to simply move the code from `someMethod()` to the `B` constructor:

```
public class B extends class A{
 Rectangle[] mPathDots=new Rectangle[30]; //initialized array with 30  nulled items

 public B(){
   int x = mPathDots.length; //error! mPathDots is null, but in theory lenght must be 30 !?
 }
}
```

Comment: That is, in this case I must use some method like init() ?

Answer (score 2):

A is created before B, and A tries to access the `mPathDots` before B is instantiated. So it fails. You could move it to `A`, like this

```
public abstract class A{
  protected Rectangle[] mPathDots=new Rectangle[30]; // <-- this would work.
  public abstract void someMethod();
  public A(){
    someMethod();  
  }
}
```

Comment: I'll use this same approach. He can also create a method like `getPathDots()` that create the array instance before call `someMethod()`.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the game here, but I still want to point out some options, for the benefit of those that stumble in here later. While both of the other answers are correct as they stand, there are still options to explore. 
One approach is to use an init method, for example:

```
public abstract class A{

     public abstract void someMethod();

     public void init(){
        someMethod();  
     }

}

public class B extends A {
     Integer[] mPathDots=new Integer[30]; //initialized array with 30  nulled items

     @Override
     public void someMethod(){
       int x = mPathDots.length; 
     }

     public B() {
         init();
     }
}
```

Another one is to initialize mPathDots in someMethod, i.e.:

```
public abstract class A{

     public abstract void someMethod();

     void A(){
        someMethod();  
     }

}

public class B extends A {
     Integer[] mPathDots; 

     @Override
     public void someMethod(){
       if (mPathDots == null) {
         mPathDots = new Integer[30];
       }
       int x = mPathDots.length; 
     }

}
```

Finally, just to get this working(!), we can of course declare mPathDots static, although it has its own obvious disadvantages:

```
public class B extends A {
     private static Integer[] mPathDots=new Integer[30]; //initialized array with 30  nulled items

     @Override
     public void someMethod(){
       int x = mPathDots.length; 
     }

}
```

This is an interesting problem, for it serves as a simple example for pointing out the role of the constructor, and what happens at the initial stages. Before the first statement of a constructor is exectued, there is always a call to the superclass constructor or call to a sibling constructor. If it is not made explicit it is hidden, i.e. injected by the compiler. So,

```
public class B {
  Integer[] mPathDots=new Integer[30]; //initialized array with 30  nulled items

  public B() {
    // mPathDots is initialized
    int x = mPathDots.length;
  }
}
```

is equivalent to

```
public class B {
  Integer[] mPathDots=new Integer[30]; //initialized array with 30  nulled items

  public B() {
    // mPathDots is NOT yet initialized!
    super();
    // mPathDots is initialized
    int x = mPathDots.length;
  }
}
```